# Making a function continuous by choosing a value at a point

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, trigonometry, continuity

Consider the function $h:\mathbb R ^2\to\mathbb R$ where
$$
h(x,y)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle \int_0^x\frac\pi x \sin \left (\frac\pi x y\right)\,dy & \text{if } x\neq 0\\[5pt] h(0,y)&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}
$$
The task is to choose $h(0,y)$ s.t. $h$ is continuous. My first thought would be choosing $h(0,y)=0$ relating to
$$
\int_c^cf=0
$$
What troubles me is that I don't know how to make sense of the expression for $x\neq 0$. $y$ is a parameter of the function $h$ but isn't $y$ also bound by the integral expression. Wouldn't this mean that for $x\neq 0$, $h(x,y)=h(x,y')$ for any $y,y'$ as they don't contribute to the value?

Comment: Choosing $h(0,y)$ so that $h$ is continuous means evaluating $ \displaystyle \lim_{x\,\to\,0} h(x,y). \qquad $

Comment: As given, it makes no sense to consider the expression as defining a function of $x$ and $y.$ The integral
$$
\int_0^x \frac \pi x \sin\left( \frac \pi x y\right) \, dy
$$
defines a function of $x,$ not a function of anything called $y. \qquad$

Comment: I thought so. And I generally would know how to proceed, just the situation with $y$ being a bounded variable confuses me. Can you shine any light on that? @MichaelHardy

Comment: Just saw your comment. Does that mean, that the parameter $y$ is essentially ignored? @MichaelHardy

Comment: I don't see that it can be taken into account. However, I might wonder if something was intended other than what is written there.

Comment: I thought so too, but this is all the information I have.

Comment: Isn't the function constant and equal to 2 if $x\neq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the given information is correct (which would be strange because $h(x,y)$ has no function of $y$) we have \begin{align}
\int_0^x \frac\pi x\sin\left(\frac\pi xy\right)\,\mathrm{d}y&=-\cos\left(\frac\pi xy\right)\bigg\rvert_0^x\\
&=-\cos\pi+1=2
\end{align}
So at every $x$ value (excluding 0) the function is simply constant 2. The choice of $h(0,y)$ must then also be 2. However as I mentioned before, something does appear off about this question since $h$ is not a function of $y$